# Type Erasure в Java

Tags: java

Почему в *Java* есть `Type Erasure`?

Comment: Вот тут посмотрите http://blog.xapie.nz/2013/12/01/erasure/

Answer (score 2):

Это был единственный способ добавить в язык обобщённые типы без нарушения обратной совместимости.